# Parse a responseText to HTML in VBScript

Tags: dom, vbscript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to retrieve HTML Class Names from a string variable created by responseText. I need to accomplish this using VBscript. Here is a sample of current code:

```
set http = createobject("Microsoft.XmlHttp")
    http.open "GET","http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/xxx-xxx?xxxxNumber=xxxxx",false
    http.send ""

dim html : set html = CreateObject("HTMLFILE")
html.write http.responseText

dim trackdate : trackdate = html.getElementByClassName("tracking-history-date").[0].value
wscript.echo trackdate
```

I'm receiving the following error: Object doesn't support this property or mehtod: 'getElementByClassName'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into this before. Although [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the `getElementsByClassName()` method doesn't seem to actually be supported. Use something like this to work around the issue:

```
For Each el In html.getElementsByTagName("...")
  If el.ClassName = "tracking-history-date" Then
    Set trackdate = el
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the info Ansgar but unfortunately I'm receiving an error: Object required: '<!DOCTYPE html>'

Comment: @jrobinson6274 Please update your question with the modified code that gives you this error. What did you put as the tag name?