# Error when attempting to get all elements with specific Class

Tags: javascript, vbscript, innerhtml, hta

I have an HTA in which I must update the `innerHTML` of a set of elements with the class `driveLetter`.  Before I do this I must obviously grab an array of all elements with this class.

I've tried doing this with JS, however I'm told via an error that both of the methods below are not supported (Tested with IE9 and IE11).  Using these functions within an HTML file works, but this is an HTA.

```
var driveLetterInstances = document.getElementsByClassName("driveLetter");
var driveLetterInstances = document.querySelectorAll(".driveLetter");
```

The errors generated by lines above -

> Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByClassName'
>   Object doesn't support property or method 'querySelectorAll'

I don't specifically have to use JS and would be open to using VBS to carry out this function, but I have no clue on how to start with that (or even if it's possible).

Comment: getElementsByClassName is supported IE9+ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: Can you replicate the problem in a fiddle?

Comment: Can you display your attempt of updating the `innerHTML` using `getElementByClassName` or `querySelectorAll` and did you use a for loop to loop through the array of elements?

Comment: I think the problem is that getElementsByCLassName returns an Array, not an element. Then you need to pick the first one.

Comment: @NewToJS - No attempt yet, I fell at the first hurdle.  Both examples in my question return an error, thus I can't try to update the `innerHTML`.  Thanks.

Comment: anyway, check this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410949/javascript-document-getelementsbyclassname-compatibility-with-ie

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7410966/3617531  this answer

Comment: @DavidGard do you know how to use a for loop? If so just use one to loop through the elements....

Comment: @NewToJS - Yes, I know how to loop. However, the issue is actually grabbing the elements; both methods via JS known to me generate an error when used in an HTA, and it is that for which I am seeking help.  Thanks.

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz - I'm having a look at the links provided, however I not the use of `querySelectorAll` in the first two I looked at, thus an error will be generated.

Comment: @DavidGard Ah right, I understand now. This is why I asked to seen an attempt but I don't know of another method so I wish you the very best in searching for a solution.

Comment: @NewToJS - Thanks. If successful I'll post, but given some of the links posted here it seems that this is actually quite a common problem with HTA files not fully supproting JS. Hopefully someone will come through with a VBS solution!

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30387087/1630171).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - YES!!!! That's done it, well found and thanks for posting.

Answer (score 2):

To replace the innerHTML of set elements you could always just do something as simple as one line like this:

**JQuery Solution 1:**

```js
// Find all the elements with the class name ".driveLetter" and replaces with "new content"
$(".driveLetter").html("new content");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- All elements with the same class name to be replaced with new content -->
<div class="driveLetter"> Hello </div>
<div class="driveLetter"> Hello </div>
<div class="driveLetter"> Hello </div>
<div class="driveLetter"> Hello </div>
```

**JQuery Solution 2:**

```js
// Loop through the classname
$('.driveLetter').each(function(key, value) {
  value.innerHTML = "New Content";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- All elements with the same class name to be replaced with new content -->
<div class="driveLetter"> Hello </div>
<div class="driveLetter"> Hello </div>
<div class="driveLetter"> Hello </div>
<div class="driveLetter"> Hello </div>
```

JQuery can be used by calling it from JQuery website or can be stored locally

**Example from getting from online**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Example from getting from local file**

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Explanation of querySelectorAll()**

I believe IE8 only supports `querySelectorAll()` in the standard mode. REF: [Check this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462057.aspx#selectorapi)

> The Selectors API is defined as part of the Selectors API
>   specification and is only available to Web pages displayed in IE8
>   standards mode.

[Selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/)

The chances are that you're not setting the proper DOCTYPE declaration; you will need to add one.

Comment: This is Jquery Chris, not javascript.

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz   "I don't specifically have to use JS" read his question

Comment: No mention of jQuery in your answer and it isn't tagged in the question. If you plan to give a jQuery solution to a question that doesn't have it tagged, I would recommend clearly displaying this is using jQuery and how to like to the library.

Comment: Then, please,edit and explain it, show the import for jquery, and maybe it could be a good answer.

Comment: Updated my answer to show how to use the JQuery solution

Comment: why downvote ?i think the answer is right . downvotes are only for incorrect and non clear and irrelevant answers.

Comment: I agree, this is a good answer (when displaying the correct information to go with the source code) but I don't see any reason for a downvote.

Comment: The answer was obviously not clear, and it was also not working without the import, and jquery was not tagged in the OP. Then, it was not a good answer.

After edition, there is not -1. That´s the -1 reason exist...

Comment: @NewToJS anyway, If you think it´s a good answer, you can upvote yourself the answer, as I did after the edit!!

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz I would place a comment to suggest an edit to link and display the relevant information before selecting a downvote.

Comment: @NewToJS I did... that´s why the question was edited... please read FIRST comment...

Comment: I did read the first comment, you placed that comment with your downvote.

Comment: We don't have to argue about the down vote, at first I didn't explain my answer fully. However I've updated it and now displays how to use JQuery

Comment: jQuery would be my weapon of choice for a website/webapp, but unfortunatly this project calls for a self-contained solution, so no external files can be included (not even via CDN, as users may not have access to the internet). Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @DavidGard you don't need internet to access JQuery, you can download the JQuery js and css files and store them locally inside the application

Comment: But that will make the applicatoin unnecessarily large for the sake of one line of code.  Pure JS should support the functionality I require, if not I suspect VBS can do the job (I just don't know how to use it). Thanks.

Comment: @DavidGard Check my updated answer and see "Explanation of querySelectorAll()"